# What's the different between OKHttp3 3.14.9 and 4.9.2? It causes SocketException with same code

Tags: okhttp

My App was using OKHttp3 3.14.9 before. It was normal to call "AAA" API and then call "BBB" API immediately. After upgrade to 4.9.2, I didn't change any code, except required change for [upgrading to OKHttp4](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/). Problem occurred. "AAA" calling was return 200. Then SocketException: Broken pipe and IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection appeared during "BBB" API calling. The request didn't send to server. I used Charles to provide this. I try to add

```
.header("Connection", "close")
```

to fix this problem. This approach seems to solve the problem. But I want to know the root cause and make sure it won't happen in sometimes.

Base on Charles, I found that both versions are the same except "Session Resumed" and "Kept Alive"  in overview. The "Session Resumed" and "Kept Alive" were "No" in 3.14.9 version. But the "Session Resumed" was "Yes" in 4.9.2 version. In 4.9.2 devDebug version, "Session Resumed" shows "N/A(Connection kept alive)" and "Yes" in "Kept Alive".

My OKHttpClient is

```
val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
okHttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.cookieJar(WebkitCookieManagerProxy())
.followRedirects(false)
.retryOnConnectionFailure(false).build()
```

Here's the request and response

```
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/AAA http/1.1
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cache-Control: no-cache
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 4647082
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Host: www.xxxx.com
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: Keep-Alive
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cookie: HTTPSBIZAPPHK=!/hIHetE6OOSfoqLMeF0cQdf86OMezNaG8DYEhDP9HmUdjbqRk1TFf/8qqyS8oQ/TXZbRS8XQvkfIgQ==; TS019e0bf9=018de30b9afd7d6b7907b55052d4bb828cd0eb5e457ef1ac86bda5de66a6dc0ee32ee35aed11af493778be36f9d0d42989051a2c5c; JSESSIONID=0000g3ZKZ6Vgj6W1acswtPybLjS:8f3c1488-34d6-4617-a01c-3939d9edb88f; HSBCHASEpersisted=_1_c54fe076c2ae4c57b4a341fe0520ec10_1648115941241_1397606692_1648196272829_5
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.2
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_1: isMobile:true
2022-03-25 16:17:58.483 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM: isAjax:true

2022-03-25 16:17:58.513 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (4647082-byte body)
2022-03-25 16:18:22.888 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/AAA (24375ms)
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2022 08:18:11 GMT
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_0: clientRequestGUID:f5a3d565-ba1a-4655-996e-85041b816d89
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_1: globalAccountName:IAMGROOT_5c759262-dd33-4e7b-83aa-ce9e068cd960
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_2: btId:1524095
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_3: btERT:122
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_4: serverSnapshotType:p
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 50
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Language: en-GB
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: S: LGBB01CPHS-WS
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: Keep-Alive
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"responseCode":"3001","message":"pending result"}
2022-03-25 16:18:22.889 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (50-byte body)
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/BBB http/1.1
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cache-Control: no-cache
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 24
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Host: www.xxxxx.com
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: Keep-Alive
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Accept-Encoding: gzip
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cookie: HTTPSBIZAPPHK=!/hIHetE6OOSfoqLMeF0cQdf86OMezNaG8DYEhDP9HmUdjbqRk1TFf/8qqyS8oQ/TXZbRS8XQvkfIgQ==; TS019e0bf9=018de30b9afd7d6b7907b55052d4bb828cd0eb5e457ef1ac86bda5de66a6dc0ee32ee35aed11af493778be36f9d0d42989051a2c5c; JSESSIONID=0000g3ZKZ6Vgj6W1acswtPybLjS:8f3c1488-34d6-4617-a01c-3939d9edb88f; HSBCHASEpersisted=_1_c54fe076c2ae4c57b4a341fe0520ec10_1648115941241_1397606692_1648196276403_5
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.2
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM_1: isMobile:true
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ADRUM: isAjax:true
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"requestID":"A7L2T1JG"}
2022-03-25 16:18:28.895 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (24-byte body)
2022-03-25 16:18:28.896 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on https://www.xxxxx.com/...
```

Anyone has idea about this? What code from OKHttp caused this problem? Is the header for close connection a perfect solution? Appreciate for any idea! Thank you